# a negative clause after "not only"?

Tags: grammar

I have searched several websites, including this forum, for finding information about using a negative clause after "not only." I found that in most cases it's not ungrammatical to use a double negative in "not only...but also". Still, the following sentence seems awkward and ungrammatical to me. Please let me know if it is incorrect, and if yes, how can I rephrase it?

"Not only did the economic growth rate not rise, but it fell."

Comment: There's no reason to use a negative clause after _but only_, and there's not reason **not** to use one. That's because there's no such thing as a "negative clause", and no general rules for their use. Negation is extremely complex, not simple like present vs past tense, or presence vs absence of _the_.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence (as it stands now, without "also") is perfectly grammatical and clear.

You could emphasise the contrast with *but it even fell*, or (expressing more surprise) *but it actually fell*.